# Is there online documentation and tutorials that can help me learn StackOverflow?

Tags: support

Meta Stack Overflow is the part of the site where users discuss the workings and policies of Stack Overflow rather than discussing programming itself.

Is there any other place, like online documentation or tutorials, that can help me learn StackOverflow?

Comment: There is nothing to discuss and there is no bug, so please don't edit in those tags.

Comment: @AshvinMonpara Why do you want the discussion and support tags? I mean, they're not a terrible thing to have together, but they're not necessary either. This is Meta and we do discuss things, such as "feature requests", "bugs", and "support" questions. The discussion tag is for when it's none of the others really, and your "support" tag tells us you want support, and so we'll discuss it :) It's certainly not worth having an editing war over ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a few primary resources:

- The [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help);
- The [tour](http://stackoverflow.stackexchange.com/tour);
- The [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) (thanks [James](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/230506/james));
- Questions tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) on the site-specific meta (thanks [MichaelT](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/213963/michaelt)).

They are available on every site, so this isn't Stack Overflow specific, and much is the same. Read the *[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)* and *[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)* articles. They are most important.

[Oded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140505/oded) pointed me to [this pluralsight course](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/using-stackoverflow-stackexchange-sites) from [Kate Gregory](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147247/kate-gregory). It seems a good start if you want a more in-depth explanation of how SE works.

Comment: There is also a [pluralsight course](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/using-stackoverflow-stackexchange-sites) by [Kate Gregory](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147247/kate-gregory).

Comment: @Oded Didn't know that existed! Thanks. Added.

Comment: And the [faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites), which expands on the help center and has a bit more here and there

Comment: @James indeed. added. Thanks.

Comment: There's also the faq tag on the various meta sites.  For example [Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq).

Comment: @MichaelT: Those get grouped in the FAQ, right? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @PatrickHofman the FAQ link provided in the answer is a document that tried to group them from pre-MSO/MSE split.  You will also find *other* sites having a [different set of FAQ resources](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) on their meta. These are often particular to how the community of a given site interprets some of the guidelines from Stack Exchange and also particular guidance about reoccurring questions and issues that come up on that site.

Comment: @MichaelT: Added.

Comment: @Oded isn't there a video of the [meet up](http://www.meetup.com/Stack-Overflow-Meetups/events/222527627/?utm_campaign=London%20Tech%20Week%20-%20Dev%20Meetup%20Page&utm_source=London%20Tech%20Week%20-%20Dev%20Meetup%20Page) where you presented [this slidedeck](http://odedcoster.com/Dev4Devs2015/#/)?

Comment: @rene - they did video the meetup, but the footage is still in post production. I am also waiting for it to go up somewhere. Though that deck is very specific to asking questions, not the rest of SE.

Comment: Link to Tour is broken