# Teaching 'How to ask questions on Stack Exchange' and a question assessment rubric

Tags: discussion, questions

I teach a high school computing, and at least for my senior classes, have thought that asking good questions on StackOverflow (or, in fact, any online forum) would be a useful skill to learn. So I'm wondering if anyone out there has explicitly taught this (either in Uni or school), and interested in sharing any curriculum material and/or assessment rubrics. Obviously there's https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask which I'd use as a starting point, but was wondering if anyone else has started on this idea?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110060/long-term-goal-automated-stackoverflow-sandbox-site-for-beginners and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259118/is-there-online-documentation-and-tutorials-that-can-help-me-learn-stackoverflow

Comment: A quick search didn't turn up a good hit but maybe in [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) you'll find better resources. Consider asking in their chat.